# NodeJS - how does it handles requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose you have the code below:

```
var http = require('http'); 
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  //Computations that takes one millisecond
  ............
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
```

**Questions:**

1. Will Node handle that callbacks in parallel?
2. What would happen if we sent more that 1 request per millisecond (let's say 3 requests simultaneously)?
3. What would happen if we sent 150 000 requests per second?

Comment: You have the code, why not write the test cases you described and see? Node is single threaded and asynchronous, so it won't handle requests in parallel. If you send multiple requests they will have to wait for the previous requests to finish

Comment: @LcLk that's the core element for understanding Node. Besides *how does it work* I want to know *why does it work in such fashion*.

Comment: Your best bet is reading some [articles](http://css.dzone.com/articles/quick-introduction-how-nodejs) and maybe even looking at the [source](https://github.com/joyent/node). It works this way because an asynchronous event based server is faster with less overhead than multithreading, and usually load balancing is done by some reverse proxy like nginx or apache pointing at multiple servers.

Answer (score 2):

Though I am new to nodejs, I will try to give some advices.

IMHO, Node doesn't handle any parallelism. It is single-thread, means only 1 process, 1 thread, 1 cpu. All his power resides in his non-blocking way of processing by using callback functions. This makes node stay rapid without the complexity of multithread.

If a single nodejs server is not enough for your huge incoming request, think of cluster to take advantage of multi-core system : http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Just google. There are lots of articles on this topic.